# Regenerate Keystore from SHA1 fingerprint

Tags: android, android-keystore

I've forgot password of one of my keystore and thus couldn't update an existing app. I've tried using brute-force method too get the password without success. So I was just wondering if it's possible to regenerate the keystore, if you have the SHA1 fingerprint?

I assume that Keystore consist of private keys and if you have the private keys you can regenerate the keystore with different password.

PS: I have the keystore file, but not the keystore password. Both Keystore and alias password was kept as same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fingerprint is derived from the key via a one-way hashing algorithm.  There is no way to reverse engineer the key from the fingerprint (and a good thing, or anybody who got your key fingerprint would have your key).  If you can't crack the password (I have no advice on that) then I think you'll have to generate a new key.  I think the problem you're trying to avoid is that then anyone with the app installed will have to uninstall it first in order to install the new version, but I don't think there's any way around it.